# Subtracting numbers as Objects - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a sorted array, yrs, which is what it sounds like (a sorted array of years). This array holds 5 objects and each is similar to the object below:

```
 __NSCFNumber * (int)1995   0x79fa3200
```

I'm trying to subtract the last item from the first item to get the date range:

```
int first_year = [yrs objectAtIndex:0];
int last_year = [yrs objectAtIndex:4];

NSInteger numberOfCols = ([last_year intValue] - [first_year intValue] ) + 1;
```

The values of the items in the array are as follows:

```
 first_year int 2078365328  2078365328 where it should be 1995
 last_year  int 2083083520  2083083520 where it should be
 numberOfCols   NSInteger   328 328
```

I honestly have no idea what's going on here.

EDIT

```
NSMutableArray * years = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray * atts = [NSMutableArray array];
for(Treatment * treatment in items)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",treatment.treatmentMolecule);
    NSNumber * startYr = [NSNumber numberWithInt:treatment.startDate.yr];
    NSNumber * endYr = [NSNumber numberWithInt:treatment.endDate.yr];

    if((![years containsObject:startYr]) && (![startYr isEqual:@0])){
        [years addObject:startYr];
    }

    if((![years containsObject:endYr]) && (![endYr isEqual:@0])){
        [years addObject:endYr];
    }
}
for(Attack * att in arrayAttack)
{
    NSNumber * startYr = [NSNumber numberWithInt:att.yr];
    if(![years containsObject:startYr])
        [years addObject:startYr];
}
//sort yrs
yrs = [years sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)^(NSNumber * yr1, NSNumber * yr2){
    return [yr1 compare:yr2];
}];
```

Comment: Show the complete code. How you you get/print the value of numberOfCols?

Comment: I still don't see where you figure out the actual value of `numberOfCols`.

Comment: But I don't understand that since we have the correct values for the first and last year, then why when they're subtracted to they generate an off number?

Comment: Again, how do you *know* that `numberOfCols` isn't correct? How do you print it? Are you using `NSLog`? If so, show the line of code. Do you use the debugger to get the value? Do you put it into a label? If so, show the code.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! The debugger was off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
int first_year = [yrs objectAtIndex:0];
```

The element in the array is an instance of `NSNumber`. Try to replace it with this:

```
NSNumber *first_year = [yrs objectAtIndex:0];
```

Even better, you can use `firstObject` and `lastObject` instead of hard codes indices.

I would write it like this:

```
NSNumber *first_year = [yrs firstObject];
NSNumber *last_year = [yrs lastObject];

NSInteger numberOfCols = ([last_year integerValue] - [first_year integerValue] ) + 1;
```

Comment: Unfortunately while first_year and last_year are displaying the proper (int)year the numberOfCols = `numberOfCols NSInteger 1145929728 1145929728`

Comment: Show the complete code. How to you print the numbers? I think there is another error in your code that you haven't shown yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
int first_year = [[yrs objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
int last_year = [[yrs objectAtIndex:4] intValue];
```

to get the integer values saved in NSNumber.

Comment: He has them saved as `NSNumber`.

Comment: Why the down vote? There is nothing wrong in this answer.

Comment: Odd, while the first_year and last_year are displaying as an int, when I subtract them and add one, I'm getting a "numberOfCols = 328"